# react-dropdown-tree-select: is it possible to move search area to the left?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dropdown-tree-select

I'm using react-dropdown-tree-select in my project and I'm wondering if it is possible to move search area ("Choose..") to the left as shown in the picture below? Does anyone have experience with it?
I read documentation and googled a lot but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks in advance!

[what I want to achieve.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ZVI.png)